# Find a boundary for an integral for a given result: Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find a boundary for an integral.

```
10 = integral (from 0 to boundary) (1+x^4)^0.5 dx
```

I already tried to declare a `sym` variable but Matlab is not able to solve it.

Comment: So what is your "given result"? Also show us what you've *tried*...

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I have been looking for.